# Network Unreachable After Updates

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, cloud

Here is my situation:
I am running the default Google Compute Engine Ubuntu 16.04 image on GCE. Everything is basically the default setup, and I allow connections to SSH, HTTP and HTTPS. Everything works until a reboot happens, at which point the network stops working. This has happened for the second time now, first time I just started from scratch, but I would like to find out what's going on now.

As best as I can tell, it happens after unattended upgrades, or manual upgrades, when the kernel is upgraded, but I'm not 100% sure.
Everything looks perfectly normal, but neither incoming nor outgoing network traffic works. I can't ping the machine, or SSH into it. I can log in via serial terminal through the Google Cloud Console. 
Here, when I try to ping the machine from outside, I do get the following message in the console:

```
Nov  1 11:40:17 instance-2 kernel: [  409.306083] IPv4: martian source 10.128.0.2 from *x.x.x.x (my ip)*, on dev ens4
Nov  1 11:40:17 instance-2 kernel: [  409.306100] ll header: 00000000: 42 01 0a 80 00 02 42 01 0a 80 00 01 08 00        B.....B.......
```

I also see some errors when booting regarding cloud-init, such as this:

```
[   26.780358] cloud-init[1177]: 2017-11-01 11:24:42,023 - util.py[WARNING]: No instance datasource found! Likely bad things to come!
[FAILED] Failed to start Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler).
```

But this is probably related to not having any network connectivity?

I can't reach anything, including the default gateway 10.128.0.1

Output of ifconfig

```
ens4      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 42:01:0a:80:00:02  
          inet addr:10.128.0.2  Bcast:10.128.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::4001:aff:fe80:2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1460  Metric:1
          RX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2186 (2.1 KB)  TX bytes:2980 (2.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Contents of /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.ens4.leases

```
lease {
  interface "ens4";
  fixed-address 10.128.0.2;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.255;
  option routers 10.128.0.1;
  option dhcp-lease-time 86400;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 169.254.169.254;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 169.254.169.254;
  option interface-mtu 1460;
  option domain-search "c.green-torus-124415.internal.", "google.internal.";
  option ntp-servers 169.254.169.254;
  option rfc3442-classless-static-routes 32,10,128,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,10,128,0,1;
  option host-name "instance-5.c.green-torus-124415.internal";
  option domain-name "c.green-torus-124415.internal";
  renew 3 2017/11/01 16:33:45;
  rebind 3 2017/11/01 16:33:45;
  expire 3 2017/11/01 16:33:45;
}
lease {
  interface "ens4";
  fixed-address 10.128.0.2;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.255;
  option routers 10.128.0.1;
  option dhcp-lease-time 86400;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 169.254.169.254;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 169.254.169.254;
  option interface-mtu 1460;
  option domain-search "c.green-torus-124415.internal.", "google.internal.";
  option ntp-servers 169.254.169.254;
  option rfc3442-classless-static-routes 32,10,128,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,10,128,0,1;
  option host-name "instance-5.c.green-torus-124415.internal";
  option domain-name "c.green-torus-124415.internal";
  renew 4 2017/11/02 01:52:41;
  rebind 4 2017/11/02 13:33:46;
  expire 4 2017/11/02 16:33:46;
}
```

So it seems the packet gets to the VM, but it thinks it's a martian packet for some reason and ignores/rejects it?

These packages were updated yesterday:

- libgnutls-openssl27:amd64
- linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic:amd64
- linux-headers-virtual-hwe-16.04:amd64

I have already tried renewing DHCP lease, and removing the new kernel and booting the previous kernel to no avail.

What can be done to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the issue was with ddclient. The same issue happened for me on Azure as well, but never happened on AWS.

I was using ddclient to update my domain records for this server. It seems that maybe GCE and Azure use ddclient during the cloud-init setup for the instance, but AWS does not. I assume this is required to let the gateway know the instance is up, etc. When I installed and made my own config for ddclient, this seems to override what happens during the instance startup, thus causing the network to not work properly. Uninstalling ddclient and removing /etc/ddclient.conf solved the issue.